# Вывод массива в Entry (поле ввода) без пробелов и запятых. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Я вывожу данные из массива `a` в поле ввода `b.Entry` таким способом: `b.insert(0, a)`,  но содержимое массива выводится через пробел

Как убрать пробелы в поле ввода?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предварительно объедините все элементы вашего массива в строку.

```
b.insert(0, "".join(a))
```

Или, если у вас список состоит не только из строк, преобразуйте их сначала в строки.

```
b.insert(0, "".join(map(str, a)))
```